# TCPDF Table of contents on each page

Tags: php, tcpdf, tableofcontents

I'm trying create a table of contents on each page of a `PDF`. Like a classic menu for navigation.

`TCPDF` has indeed a Table of Content Index function which does something similar after Bookmarking each page. But this only creates an isolated page `(e.g. $pdf->addTOCPage())`.

I need the table of contents on all bookmarked pages. As far as I've read the `TCPDF` documentation, the TOC functions only works after all pages have been bookmarked. This is obvious an issue because I need the links on each page before that.

I think another solution would be with JS. But I have no idea how to link the events with each page. And I've read that it's better to avoid using js with pdf's.

Thank you

Well I think I found a solution:

a. create each page and bookmark it

```
$pdf->AddPage(); <br /> 
$pdf->Bookmark();
```

b. edit created page and add to it the tabel of contents

```
$pdf->SetPage(page number); <br />
$pdf->addHTMLTOC();
```

But the solution that fits me perfectly is to write as html:

```
<a href="#1">Page 1</a>
```

Where `#1` is the PDF page number.

Comment: You can`t know what the page number is when you writing some page, cause later you can insert some pages before this pages and your numeration will be wrong

Answer (score 0):

like index page before content?

I am using following page to generate index page. Hope this will help

```
    $pdf->addTOCPage();
    $pdf->setColor('text',34,34,34);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(20);
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, 'Table Of Contents', 1, 'C', 0, 1, '', '', true, 0);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
    $pdf->addTOC(2, '', '', 'INDEX', '', array(34,34,34));
    $pdf->endTOCPage();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have managed to make it work by using the page number (#1). It gives me much more control...